# Make Org Chart with interop excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to create an excel worksheet with an organizational chart with data from a database.

I have played around with the interop excel library in a c# console application, but i am stuck.

I can make a worksheet containing a smartart object with the hierachy chart layout(Org chart), but i dont know how to add my own data to it. When you create the chart it comes with the nodes shown in the picture below.

Is it even possible to add you own data to the chart through the interop excel library?

This is my code so far:

```
    private static Excel.Workbook Wb = null;
    private static Excel.Application Xl = null;
    private static Excel.Worksheet Sheet = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Xl = new Excel.Application();
        Xl.Visible = true;
        Wb = Xl.Workbooks.Add();
        Sheet = Wb.Worksheets[1];

        var myLayout = Xl.SmartArtLayouts[88];

        var smartArtShape = Sheet.Shapes.AddSmartArt(myLayout, 50, 50, 200, 200);

        smartArtShape.AlternativeText = "Test";

    }
```

This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the functionality is accessible through the "interop" :-) It's just a bit... arcane, especially for those who don't come from PowerPoint.

Since a SmartArt is "wrapped" in a `Shape` object, it's first necessary to get the `Shape`, then through it the `SmartArt` - the `Shape` object has `HasSmartArt` (test) and `SmartArt` (use) properties.

(Note that I find it very useful to explicitly declare the object *type*, rather than rely on *var* to "guess". That helps immensely when trouble-shooting.)

The actual content (the "boxes") are `Nodes`. For some reason, the PIAs don't provide Node objects (but they are present in the COM object model), so accessing them is a bit round-about in C#. To get all the nodes, use the `AllNodes` property to return the collection.

The Node objects can then be addressed collection indexing `nds[i]`. An individual node can be assigned to a `SmartArtNode` or to an Office `Shape` object. For the purposes of this question - adding text - the next step is the same...

The "boxes" are, themselves, Office Drawing Text Boxes (`Shapes`) and have the `TextFrame2.TextRange.Text` property for accessing their content. (Note that the default content is actually a placeholder, so this property will not *return* anything for a newly created SmartArt.)

Note: The code in the question attempts to use `AlternativeText` - this is like "AltText" in HTML objects, it provides accessibilty information and is not relevant for what you're trying to do.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet) wb.Worksheets[1];

    var myLayout = excelApp.SmartArtLayouts[88];

    var smartArtShape = ws.Shapes.AddSmartArt(myLayout, 50, 50, 200, 200);

    if (smartArtShape.HasSmartArt == Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
    {
      Office.SmartArt smartArt = smartArtShape.SmartArt;
      Office.SmartArtNodes nds = smartArt.AllNodes;

      for (int i = 1; i <= nds.Count; i++)
      {
          Office.SmartArtNode nd = nds[i]; //both work
          var shpNode = nd.Shapes.Item(1);
          nd.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Testing Node " + i;
          shpNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Testing Shape " + i;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes much more sense now, but i seems to have problems placing the nodes in the right order. Do this look right to you?: https://github.com/strookers/ExcelOrgChart/blob/master/ExcelOrgChart/Program.cs

Comment: I don't really actually *use* SmartArt, so looking at that code doesn't mean much to me, I'm afraid... But if you're unsure, ask a new question, including that code, with screen shots of the result it gives, plus the result you want (created manually), with a bit of explanation. I'll be happy to look (if no one beats me to it) and apply the logic I have to the problem :-)

Comment: Thank you again. I have created the following Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455280/smartart-nodes-being-added-incorrectly-in-excel-worksheet-with-interop-excel-in