# Add hyperlink to smartart node with interop-excel in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have an c# console application which create an excel worksheet containing a smartart object with the hiearchy layout(OrgChart). I would like to add hyperlinks to the nodes within the org chart, but somehow i can't.

In the picture below, i would like to add a hyperlink to "Node 1"(1) which will take me to the "LinkedSheet" sheet(2):
[image: Org chart hyperlink picture]

with the following code snippet, i tried to add a hyperlink to the sheet "orgChart" where the textFrame of "Node 1"(var name: ndTop) is the anchor and the sheet "LinkedSheet" is the target:

```
Sheet.Hyperlinks.Add(ndTop.TextFrame2, "", "'" + LinkSheet.Name + "'!A1", "", "");
```

But i get the following error:
[image]
The error translated to english: 
'The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE) '.
There are no inner exception.

I added the following references to my project:

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (Nuget package).
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library (COM library from add reference)

The usings:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
```

The Code:

```
    private static Excel.Workbook Wb = null;
    private static Excel.Application Xl = null;
    private static Excel.Worksheet Sheet = null;
    private static Excel.Worksheet LinkSheet = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Xl = new Excel.Application();
        Xl.Visible = true;
        Wb = Xl.Workbooks.Add();
        LinkSheet = Wb.Worksheets[1];
        LinkSheet.Name = "LinkedSheet";

        Sheet = Wb.Worksheets.Add();
        Sheet.Name = "OrgChart";


        var myLayout = Xl.SmartArtLayouts[88];

        var smartArtShape = Sheet.Shapes.AddSmartArt(myLayout, 50, 50, 200, 200);

        if (smartArtShape.HasSmartArt == Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {
            Office.SmartArt smartArt = smartArtShape.SmartArt;
            Office.SmartArtNodes nds = smartArt.AllNodes;
            Office.SmartArtNode ndTop = null;
            foreach (Office.SmartArtNode nd in nds)
            {
                if (nd.Level != 1)
                {
                    nd.Delete();
                }
                else
                {
                    ndTop = nd;
                    ndTop.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Node 1";
                }
            }

            //Adding the hyperlink
            Sheet.Hyperlinks.Add(ndTop.TextFrame2, "", "'" + LinkSheet.Name + "'!A1", "", "");

            Office.SmartArtNode ndLev2_1 = ndTop.AddNode(Office.MsoSmartArtNodePosition.msoSmartArtNodeBelow);
            ndLev2_1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Node 1.1";

            Office.SmartArtNode ndLev2_2 = ndTop.AddNode(Office.MsoSmartArtNodePosition.msoSmartArtNodeBelow);
            ndLev2_2.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Node 1.2";

            Office.SmartArtNode ndLev2_3 = ndTop.AddNode(Office.MsoSmartArtNodePosition.msoSmartArtNodeBelow);
            ndLev2_3.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Node 1.3";

            Office.SmartArtNode ndLev2_1_1 = ndLev2_1.AddNode(Office.MsoSmartArtNodePosition.msoSmartArtNodeBelow);
            ndLev2_1_1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Node 1.1.1";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you state the error message and add usings / references to your code?

Comment: @WolfgangJacques I have added a picture of the exception and the usings/references

Comment: Just a quick question, are you trying manipulating `.xls` files or just `.xslx`, if it is just `.xslx` you may want to consider switching off of the interop libraries to the more modern SDK Microsoft that provides for interacting with office files (which as a bonus does not need office installed on the computer doing the work unlike the interop). It is called OpenXML but that is just the name of the file format that `.xslx` files (and other office files that start with `.x*)` use. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

Comment: I personally have never worked with SmartArt, but if I had to guess where to start it would be with the [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.diagrams) namespace.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The main purpose of the console application is to create an excel worksheet(.xlsx) with an Smartart(Org Chart) object. If you can both create a Smartart object and manipulate the nodes within that smartart object, it would definitely be worth a look. Do you you know if this is possible?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thank you.. I will definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Michael, it appears the problem has to do with this being an `Office.Shape` rather than an `Excel.Shape` and Office/Excel doesn't allow a type cast from `Office.Shape` to `Excel.Shape` - not even in VBA - I get the same error in VBA. The Excel *UI* allows appending a Hyperlink, but the object model does not - at least, not that I can find. My recommendation at this point would be to ask the question "How can I add a hyperlink to a SmartArtNode" with the [excel]  and [vba] tags to get the experts on it. If you can't cobble together a VBA example ping me and I'll post.

Comment: Note: The Open XML route would certainly also be possible and should be able to solve this problem. But Excel Open XML is a very complex proposition. Unless you can start with existing workbooks and just need to add the smart art.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you again. I might have to take you up on that. I am trying to put together an example with vba, but since i dont have that much experience i dont know where to start. I found the following example: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/554224-using-vba-smart-art.html. but i dont know how to implement it in excel.

Comment: OK, next time I'm at my main machine (mobile device, late evening as I write this) I'll pull out the sample Excel VBA I used to research this and ask a question under the tags excel and VBA. If not tomorrow, then probably Friday. One question, though, as there's an aspect that's occurred to me that I haven't tested, yet: Must the hyperlink be on the entire box, or would it suffice if it were on the `TextFrame2.TextRange`?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you so much. It is prefered if it is the entire node, but it will be fine if it is just the text range.

Comment: posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527055/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-smartart-node