# Add a Hyperlink to a SmartArt Node

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

In the Excel (also PowerPoint and Word) user interface it's possible to assign a hyperlink to a SmartArt node, or text in a node:

[image: Add hyperlink to SmartArt in UI]

Recording these steps in a macro yields an empty procedure.

Trying to use logic with the object model yields no useful result (see code below). I tried the following three approaches:

1. A `SmartArtNode` has a `Shapes` property and one can extract a `Shape` object... But the type belongs to the Office object model (`Office.Shape`) and cannot be coerced (that I can find) to an `Excel.Shape` (nor to a `PowerPoint.Shape`). Trying to assign it to an `Excel.Shape` - `Set xlShape = nd1.Shapes(1)` - results in

> Run-time error '13' 
>   Type mismatch

2. Trying to add a hyperlink to the `Office.Shape` results in

> Run-time error -2147417848 (80010108)
>
> Automation error
>   The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

3. Then I tried selecting the node and adding the hyperlink to `Application.Selection` (`TypeName(Application.Selection)` returns `Shape`) which returned

> Run-time error 1004
>    Application-defined or object-defined error

How does one add a hyperlink to a SmartArt node?

```
Sub AddHyperlinkToSmartArtNode()
  Dim sa As SmartArt
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim nd1 As SmartArtNode
  Dim shp As Office.Shape
  Dim shpx
  Dim rng As TextRange2

  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set sa = ws.Shapes(1).SmartArt
  Set nd1 = sa.Nodes(1)

  'Dim xlShape As Excel.Shape
  'Set xlShape = nd1.Shapes(1)
  'Run-time error '13'
  'Type mismatch

  Set shp = nd1.Shapes(1)

  'ws.Hyperlinks.Add shp, "www.google.com"
  'Run-time error -2147417848 (80010108)
  'Automation error
  'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

  Set rng = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
  rng.Select
  Set shpx = Application.Selection
  ws.Hyperlinks.Add shpx, "www.google.com"
  'Run-time error 1004
  'Application-defined or object-defined error
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks to me like an Excel object model deficiency. I was able to record this in Word and it runs successfuly:
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="http://brandwares.com/", SubAddress:="" But the analogous line in Excel returns only Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.